# How to stop control resizing when removing anchoring?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

When removing an anchoring, a control can automatically resize itself to some other size.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Drop a control on a form

   [image]
2. Set an anchor

   [image]
3. Resize the form; watch the control resize with it:

   [image]
4. Remove the anchor:

   [image]
5. Watch the control resize itself without permission:

   [image]

Comment: Blame `ExplicitWidth` for that. You can [`disable storing them`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2477072/960757).

Comment: A hard-to-remember workaround is to change the width of the memo (in your case) either manually editing in OI or by mouse, in between steps 3 and 4.

Comment: @TLama shouldn't you add your comment as an answer? Or it doesn't stop the auto resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create control, It gets initial parameters. Among them there are `height` and `width`. When you enable anchoring and resize form, the control also resizes, but initial parameters don't change. Thats why, when you remove anchoring, it gets its initial size.